# SCP from docker image on elastic beanstalk

Tags: docker, elastic-beanstalk

I need to get a file from the docker image running on AWS Elastic Beanstalk.

I can SSH into the EB instance, but after that I have no idea what to do.

`sudo docker images` shows two images, one with my app name and the other called `aws-beanstalk/current-app`.

Comment: You can't use `docker exec` on an image, it is used to run a command in a running container.

Comment: Thanks. https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTTjAmb2ScdNRBXb7g3bJyzFo9SM2CESQ7DpeXo2uq4eG3GRwhXfw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of copying a file would be to do it from the container. If you have a running container, use `docker cp` to transfer the file to your host, in this case the EB instnace.

Run `docker ps` to get the container ID. If you don't see any output, launch a container based on the image you are interested in. Say, if your image name is 'aws-beanstalk/current-app' -

`docker run -ti --rm aws-beanstalk/current-app /bin/bash`

Then from the docker host, for instance to transfer a file under /code/run.py on the container to /tmp on the host:

`docker cp containerID:/code/run.py /tmp`

The containerID is the one you see after running `docker ps`

You can also use `docker exec -ti containerID /bin/bash` to interactively work on an already running container.

Comment: The docker cp command didn't understand wildcards, but copying a file at a time worked. Thanks.